# Joi decimal, less than 8 decimal places

Tags: javascript, reactjs, joi

Need your help in setting up the library schema for Joi. Task, you need to do validation if the number of characters exceeds 8 characters after commas. I did it using custom validation, but I would like to use Joi use everywhere in the project:

```
   myField: Joi.number()
    .positive()
    .less(999999999999)
    .required()
    .error(() => ({
      message: 'Error',
    })),
```

> 4,23443234  - valid data
>
> 4,234432341 - invalid data

Answer (score 9):

You can find the solution by reading [Joi's documentation](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.3.1/API.md#numberprecisionlimit):

> ### `number.precision(limit)`
>
> Specifies the maximum number of decimal places where:
>
> - `limit` - the maximum number of decimal places allowed.
>
> ```
> const schema = Joi.number().precision(2);
> ```

Using `precision` will by default just round the decimals to the specified maximum. If you want it to fail the validation instead, set `convert` to `false` as per the [documentation](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.3.1/API.md#validatevalue-schema-options-callback):

```
joi.validate(objectToValidate, schema, {convert:false});
```

Comment: I found it and tried to use, but it doesn't work at all

Comment: You have to be more specific than "it doesn't work". What have you tried (show code)? What would you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: I already showed you a piece of code where it is configured in the Joi scheme. And this code works fine, I just want to add a decimal check. I don't understand why you put me dislike

Comment: The code you posted does not include `precision`. We can't help you with code that you do not show. How did you try to use it? What did not work? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: myField: Joi.number().precision(8)
    .positive()
    .less(999999999999)
    .required()
    .error(() => ({
      message: 'Error',
    })),